# Applying directional derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A spaceship is at location $(1,1,1)$ and the temperature of the ship's hull when at location $(x,y,z$ will be 
$$
T(x,y,z) = 200 +e^{-x^2-2y^2-3z^2}
$$
where x,y,z are in meters.

a) In what direction should the ship proceed in order to decrease temperature most rapidly?

b) If the ship travels at $e^8$ m/sec, how fast will the temperature decrease if it proceeds in this direction

Since $\nabla T(x,y,z) = (-2xe^{-x^2-2y^2-3z^2},-4ye^{-x^2-2y^2-3z^2},-6ze^{-x^2-2y^2-3z^2}) $ we have that T has continuous partials so T is differentiable and so we know that the largest rate of change occurs in the direction $\nabla T(1,1,1) = (-2e^{-6},-4e^{-6},-6e^{-6})$ Would this be the direction the ship should proceed in order to decrease temperature most rapidly? How do we know temperature will decrease?

Comment: Is it decreasing or increasing?

Comment: Do you have a y missing in the 2nd component, and a z missing in the 3rd component?  (The gradient gives the direction of maximum rate of increase of the function values.)

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. So would this be the correct direction? Or is it the direction of maximum increase of temperature?

Comment: It's the direction of maximum increase of temperature.

Comment: How would you find the direction of maximum decrease of temperature then?

Comment: @rmzerp:  Imagine you are on a hill.  If the direction of greatest increase is due north, what is the direction of greatest decrease?